# Merge two objects with override in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to merge two objects, override properties but keep properties that are not been overridden.

Example: I have the following Objects

```
const theme = {
 colors: {
  base: '#fff',
  accent: '#ff0000'
 }
}
```

and

```
const themeOverride = {
 colors: {
  accent: '#ff8900'
 }
}
```

and would like to merge these together to get

```
const newTheme = {
  colors: {
   base: '#fff',
   accent: '#ff8900'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to merge the property color of theme and themeOverride, you can do it by the code below:

```js
var theme = {
 colors: {
  base: '#fff',
  accent: '#ff0000'
 }
};
var themeOverride = {
 colors: {
  accent: '#ff8900'
 }
};
Object.assign(theme.colors, themeOverride.colors);
console.log(theme);
```

Comment: While this answers the specific example in the question, it doesn't really help in the broader sense, given the example is called `theme` and `colors`, it's probably safe to assume there will be further sub-properties (eg `fonts`, `borders` and the like) that would also need to be merged.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge these objects

Update existing object

```js
const theme = {
  colors: {
    base: '#fff',
    accent: '#ff0000'
  }
}

const themeOverride = {
  colors: {
    accent: '#ff8900'
  }
}

Object.assign(theme.colors, themeOverride.colors)

console.log(theme)
```

Or create new object

```js
const theme = {
  colors: {
    base: '#fff',
    accent: '#ff0000'
  }
}

const themeOverride = {
  colors: {
    accent: '#ff8900'
  }
}

newTheme = { colors: Object.assign({}, theme.colors, themeOverride.colors) }

console.log(newTheme)
```

Comment: Maybe you want `Object.assign({}, theme.colors, themeOverride.colors)`

Comment: `Object.assign({}, theme.colors, themeOverride.colors)` -> `{"base": "#fff", "accent": "#ff8900"}`. But it will be new object, right.

Answer (score 2):

You could merge by iterateing all properties for update with a recursive approach for objects.

```js
function merge(target, source) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (key) {
        if (source[key] && typeof source[key] === 'object') {
            merge(target[key] = target[key] || {}, source[key]);
            return;
        }
        target[key] = source[key];
    });
}

var theme = { colors: { base: '#fff', accent: '#ff0000' } }, 
    themeOverride = { colors: { accent: '#ff8900' } };
    
merge(theme, themeOverride);

console.log(theme);
```

Answer (score 1):

JS doesn't have a built-in way to do this, but it's very simple to do with Lodash, or Underscore's `_.merge()` or Ramda's `_.mergeDeepLeft()`, all of which recursively merge objects.

```js
const theme = {
 colors: {
  base: '#fff',
  accent: '#ff0000'
 }
}

const themeOverride = {
 colors: {
  accent: '#ff8900'
 }
}

const newTheme = _.merge(theme, themeOverride);

console.log(newTheme);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Kinda curious why this got so many downvotes.

Comment: upvoted just because I think the downvote are not legit. You are answering OP question and explaining your point fairly. 

Have a good day and thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with old `theme` as initial value. Try something like this:

```js
const theme = {
  colors: {
    base: '#fff',
    accent: '#ff0000'
  },
}

const themeOverride = {
  colors: {
    accent: '#ff8900'
  },
  border: {
    borderWidth: '2px'
  }
}

const newTheme = Object.keys(themeOverride).reduce((prev, key) => {
  prev[key] = Object.assign({}, theme[key] || {}, themeOverride[key])
  return prev
}, Object.assign({}, theme))

console.log(newTheme)
```

Note, this solution expects maximum 2 level nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate both objects, look for intersection and override in that instance; else, just copy as such;

```js
const theme = {
 colors: {
  base: '#fff',
  accent: '#ff0000'
 }
}

const themeOverride = {
 colors: {
  accent: '#ff8900'
 }
}
window.onload = mergeObjects(theme,themeOverride)

function mergeObjects(base,override) {
   var mergedObj = {'colors' : {}};
   for(key in base["colors"]) {
      if(override['colors'][key] == undefined) {
        mergedObj['colors'][key] = base['colors'][key]
      }
      else {
        mergedObj['colors'][key] = override['colors'][key]
      }
   }
   console.log('mergedObject is',mergedObj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could recursively look through your object and assign your new updated values this way.

Here, I made a function for it :

```js
const theme = {
 colors: {
  base: '#fff',
  accent: '#ff0000'
 }
}

const themeOverride = {
 colors: {
  accent: '#ff8900'
 }
}

function overrideObject(o1,o2){
  var res = {};
  //Go through all your attributes
  for (var a in o1){
    //Begin recursive method if another object is detected
    if(typeof o1[a] == 'object'){
      res[a] = overrideObject(o1[a],o2[a])
    }
    //Clone old data & update it if necessary
    else{
      res[a] = o1[a]; 
      if(typeof o2[a] != 'undefined') res[a] = o2[a]; 
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}

console.log(overrideObject(theme,themeOverride));
```